# Как обновить функцию из другого файла python?

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, функции

Я делаю парсинг сайта с погодой, беру переменную итемс и темп. Переменная у меня зписывается при запуске файла. Как сделать так, чтобы при команде переменная брала новую информацию с сайта?

Вот код программы, из которой я хочу обновить переменную(в условии elif msg == "погода"):

```
from sinoptik import *
from data import *

def function(): 
    try:
        vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = main_token)
        session_api = vk_session.get_api()
        longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

        def sender(id, text):
            vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.to_me:
        
                    msg = event.text.lower()
                    id = event.user_id
            
                    if msg == 'начать':
                        sender(id, 'Привет. Для того, чтобы узнать список команд, напиши "Помощь".')
                    elif msg == 'помощь':
                        sender(id, 'Список команд:\n\n❓Помощь - Выводит список команд.\n⛅️Погода - Выводит погоду на сегоднящний день.\n⌚Время - Выводит точное время.\nДата - Выводит текущую дату.')
                    elif msg == 'погода':
                        sender(id, 'Температура в городе: ' + temp + '.\n' + items)
                    elif msg == 'время':
                        time = update_time()
                        sender(id, 'Точное время: ' + str(time) + '.')
                    elif msg == 'дата':
                        day = update_date()
                        weekday = update_weekday()
                        month = update_month()
                        sender(id, 'Сегодня: ' + weekday + ', ' + str(day) + ' ' + month + '.')
    except:
        function()
function()
```

Вот код парсера:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://sinoptik.com.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA-101500607/"
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.57', 'accept': '*/*'}


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    global items, temp
    items = soup.find('div', class_='weather__article_description-text').get_text()
    temp = soup.find('div', class_='weather__article_main_temp').get_text(strip=True)

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("Error HTML: " + html.status_code)
parse()
```

Comment: добавить в ветку elif код, который парсит сайт

Comment: я хочу сделать красивый код. думал об этом. но если бы переменная выходила из другого файла, было бы лучше

Comment: @СашаГоголь а что 'не красивого' в вызове функции, которая вернет переменные?

Comment: @asanisimov я пытаюсь сделать код максимально "упорядоченным", по-этому для каждой функции стараюсь сделать свой файл python